# Checking probability question answer

Tags: probability

I apologize upfront for any spelling mistakes, I'm not used to writing math in english!

This question was taken from a test done by those willing to undertake a Master's course in Statistics in Federal University of Belo Horizonte (Brazil). I don't have access to its solution so I would like to check with you guys if my resolution seems good and see if you have any other interesting ways of solving it.

*"Joseph and Mary play the following game: from a box containing 5 black balls
and 2 white balls, they alternately withdraw balls, without replacing them.
The winner will be the one who withdraws a white ball first.
Determine the probability of Mary winning the game, assuming that she withdraws first, then Joseph, and so on."*

I went and called the probability of her winning P, as in:

$$P = {P_1} + {P_2} + {P_3} +...+ {P_n}$$

Where ${P_n}$ stands for the chance of her winning on the n-withdraw. So to win on "round 1", she can pull 2 white balls from a total of 7; to win on her round 2, she needs to miss her first pull, then Joseph has to fail too for her to get it right; and I went on following that thought. It is detailed below:

$$\eqalign{
  & {P_1} = {2 \over 7}  \cr 
  & {P_2} = {5 \over 7}{4 \over 6}{2 \over 5} = {4 \over {21}}  \cr 
  & {P_3} = {5 \over 7}{4 \over 6}{3 \over 5}{2 \over 4}{2 \over 3} = {{24} \over {252}}  \cr 
  & {P_4} = 0  \cr 
  & {P_5} = 0  \cr 
  & ... \cr} $$

After all that, I got 0,57 or 4/7 as final answer:

$$P = 0,2857 + 0,1905 + 0,0952 \approx 0,57$$

Thank you in advance for any inputs you guys may have. Cheers

Comment: Looks right to me -- so does your English.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. Good question with a proposed strategy. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, here is a way to do it using combinations ...

There are 7 balls, 2 of which are white five are black
think of an ordered arrangement of the balls as a 7 character string e.g. "BBWBWB"

There are $\binom 72=21$ equally probable arrangements of balls

To win on the first selection the arrangement must start with "W"

There are  $\binom 61=6 $ equally probable arrangements  like this( you just have to decide where to put the second "W" in the 6 remaining places)

To win on her second selection the arrangement must start with "BBW"

There are  $\binom 41=4 $ equally probable arrangements like this ( you just have to decide where to put the second "W" in the 4 remaining places)

To win on her thirrd selection the arrangement must start with "BBBBW"

There are  $\binom 21=2$ equally probable arrangements like this ( you just have to decide where to put the second "W" in the 2 remaining places)

so $$ P(WIN) = \frac{ \binom 61+\binom 41+\binom 21 }{ \binom 72}=\frac{12}{21} $$

Comment: This was great. Thank you very much